# Injecting image caption info in a semantically correct way

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-markup

I'm working on an image gallery, and hoping to get some assistance with (dynamically) inserting caption info for each image into a DIV in a semantically correct way. In it's current state, I'm using jQuery in the form of a click function to grab the information from the respective "title" and "rel" anchor attributes and insert them into a DIV with the ID "caption" as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#image_nav a").click(function(){

        $("#caption").empty();

        $("#caption").append('<em></em><span></span>')

        var capTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        var capInfo = $(this).attr("rel");

        $("#caption em").html(capTitle);

        $("#caption span").html(",&nbsp;" + capInfo); return false;
    });

});
```

I realize that this is **not** a good approach with respect to **semantics**--particularly in using the "rel" attribute for the caption info-- and I'm wondering what might be the best approach. I was contemplating using a custom data-attribute for the anchor such as "data-caption"? I have a working prototype set up [here](http://nickpish.com/_dev/openseadragon-test).

Thanks for any insight here.

Comment: use the <figcaption> tag for image captions, and <figure> instead of div for the item container.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response dan; I suppose for each list item I could include a <figcaption> that's set to "display:none" from which I could pull the data. How specifically would I reference the info in this way via jQuery?

Comment: Just as a follow up-- is there anything wrong with using a data-attribute for an anchor from which I can pull the caption info?

Comment: actually, for dynamic content it probably doesn't matter as much what the markup tags are. figures are for hard-coded image+description items, not viewers. that aside, data- would be better than mis-using the rel attrib. for great sematics, you can use the aria attribs describedby and labelledby